# Probability of die rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I have the following question:

> A die is rolled $n$ random times.
>
> The probability of it being rolled $i$ times is $\cfrac{1}{2^i}$
>
> 1. Given that the die is rolled twice, what's the probability of the sum of the outcomes being $4$?
> 2. What's the probability of the sum being $4$, given that the die was rolled an even amount of times.

In the first question, I've defined $A=\text{"the die was rolled twice"}$, $B=\text{"the sum is 4"}$

I wanted to calculate $\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$ which is $$\frac{\frac3{36}\times\frac14}{\frac{8}{36}}=\frac3{32}$$

And in the second one $A=\text{"the sum is 4"}$, $B=\text{"the die was rolled an even amount of times"}$, so it's $\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$ again.

This is where I get confused, I know that $P(B) =\frac14+\frac1{16}$ because it's either $2$ or $4$ rolls, and $P(A)=\frac{8}{36}$ like before I guess.

I'm having trouble with $P(B|A)$.

Maybe everything I've presented is wrong I'm not sure, can anyone help?

Comment: "The die is rolled n times. The probability of it being rolled i times is..."
As it is rolled n times (and we can assume n to be fixed), the probability is 1 if i = n and 0 otherwise... So you might want to edit this point. :)

Comment: @Bemte Would you be happier if we said "The die is thrown $N$ times, where $N$ is a random variable distributed the following way..."? Because that's how I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you should not find the conditional probability as it is given that you have rolled the dice twice so you should not take the probability that they did roll it twice into account.

As for the second question, you could've approached it much easier. First as you noticed the only possibilities are $4$ and $2$ rolls. So instead of defining $B$ as the probility the number of rolls is even, define $B_2$ as the probability you roll twice and $B_4$ the probability you roll $4$ times and so on. Therefore the probability you roll twice given $A$, where $A$ is the fact the roll was even. $$P(B_{2}|A) = \frac{P(B_2)}{P(A)} = \frac{1}{4P(A)}$$

and the same is for $4$ times
$$P(B_{4}|A) = \frac{P(B_4)}{P(A)} = \frac{1}{16P(A)}$$

Now to compute $P(A)$ notice it is just this sum
$$P(A)  = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2i}} = \frac{1}{3}$$ 
and the probability the sum is $4$, lets call this event $C$
given the number of rolls is even is 
$$P(C|A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(C|B_{2n})P(B_{2n}|A) = P(C|B_2)P(B_2|A) + P(C|B_4)P(B_4|A) + 0$$

Now $P(C|B_2) = \frac{1}{12}$ and $P(C|B_4) = \frac{1}{6^4}$. Now just compute it and you're done.